# Rails app - how to add a query parameter in API get request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple Item model and "/items" as well as "/items.json" work. However I want to add a search parameter in the API call like "/items.json?skuid=123" and json returned will only have the Items where the skuid=123.

I tried the following approach:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /items
  # GET /items.json
  def index
    Rails.logger.debug("index.params=#{params}")
    @items = Item.all(params.slice(*Item.attribute_names))
  end
```

But got the error

> wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

Please advice.

Comment: i think you have to first check `skuid` params is prasent or not than you can use active record `where` caluse like this way `Item.where("skuid=?",params[:skuid])`

Comment: Thanks. Partial success. "/items.json?skuid=123" works thanks to your suggestion. I got the items returned whose skuid was "123" but now "/items.json" is returning empty json. earlier it used to return all items from the database. Can you advice ?

Comment: use if block to handle search item and you have done

Comment: let me know if you have any issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would refactor your code to be scoped.

In your `Item` Model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :by_sku_id, -> (sku_id) { where(sku_id: sku_id) if sku_id.present? }
end
```

Then in your `Item` controller:

```
def index
  @items = Item.by_sku_id(params[:sku_id])
end
```

This alleviates the issue of worrying if your parameters are set or not inside your controller; overall simplifying the controller code. You can also chain these scopes and keep your API flexible.

Comment: This works! I had to read on scopes to understand what you did there. Its elegant. thanks!